# Dropdown select not working in selenium with python after updating to 3.0.1

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

i have a certain drop down with tag Select that i wanna access using Selenium webdribver. My FireFox version is 45 and language is python. now a quick note all this was working before i updated the selenium from 2.5x to 3.0.1. below is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
<logging into the site and switching frame>

drpdwn=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@name='name']"))
drpdwn.select_by_value("name1")
```

the only error it throws is no element of value name1 is found. and when i see the script running the code doesn't go to the drop down and access it. however if i do a `find_element_by_name("name").click()`  then code does go to the drop down perfectly.

if i do a `print(drpdwn)` then i get the answer as:

```
selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x0151FE70
```

has something changed for 3.0.1?

Comment: What if you print out the following `[elm.get_attribute("value") for elm in drpdwn.options]`?

Comment: sorry not sure how to use elm. never used it.

Comment: elm is just a variable alecxe assigned, try printing the line he provided

Comment: ok i did this, fresh laptop installed everything, eclipse, python n selenium n tried the code and it worked. also uninstalled on my current laptop(one which i want the code to work on) re installed everything and tried and m still stuck with the issue. its something related to my setup. the code seems fine. m trying to search if there are any env variables etc need to be setup.